# Looking for way to conditionally include "img src=" in HTML on iPad but not iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, ios, mobile-safari

Trying to write html help files that get included with our app on iOS.

For the iPad version, I want the help files to display a smallish graphic (about
156x204).
For iPhone / iPod, I don't want to have the graphic displayed.

Other than using javascript like the following in the file h_login.html:

`if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
         location.replace("h_small_login.html");`

which requires a clone of each file, I haven't found a method.

Would prefer to stay using minimal HTML ... vanilla, no CSS, a single "meta" at the
start to specify:
   meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.5; maximum-scale=4.0; user-scalable=1;"

thanks!
Stan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By far the easiest way is with a media query. I'm fairly sure i-Devices support this feature of CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 600px) {
   img.hide {display:none;}
}
```

Just add `class="hide"` to the relevant images, and adjust the `600px` (I don't know what the resolution of iPhone and iPad are, but just change the `600` to anything in between the two).

It is far easier to do this than to try and get JavaScript to do the same thing.

Comment: I don't know about the css and client-side, but I know that on the server-side, attempting to determine the screen width of an iPhone (or Android phone) via .NET isn't a good indicator of screen size, as they both return 640px.

Comment: @saluce Maybe, but I think the point is to hide images on smaller screens in general.

Comment: I did find this, so it sounds like its a good solution: http://perishablepress.com/target-iphone-and-ipad-with-css3-media-queries/

Answer (score 1):

jQuery can do this easily:

```
if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
    $("img").attr("display","none");
}
```

That would remove all images from the document when the useragent is iPhone or iPod.  If you aren't using jQuery, but you are using server-side scripting, we'd need to know what language you are using.  If you are just using straight HTML, then JavaScript is your only way to modify the page, and jQuery will be your best bet.